# Javascript strings to object

Tags: javascript

I have two strings, one a key and one a value, which I would like to turn into an object and concatenate in a loop. For example:

```
var data = {};
// loop starts here
  var a_key = 'element';
  var a_val = 'value';
  var a_obj = // somehow this equals { "element":"value" }
  data = data.concat(a_obj);
// loop ends here
```

I'm just not sure how to create an object from those two strings! Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
var a_obj = new Object();
a_obj[a_key] = a_val
```

, no?  (I'm not in a position to test this at the moment so take it with a pinch of salt...)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really make sense to concatenate something to a object without a key.  Perhaps `data` should be an array of objects?

```
data = [];
a_obj = {};
a_obj[a_key] = a_val;
data += a_obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a_key = 'key';
var a_val = 'value';
var a_obj = {};
a_obj[a_key] = a_val;
```

Note:

```
var a_obj = {}
```

and

```
var a_obj = new Object();
```

are the same, but {} feels cleaner and is recommended by [Douglas Crockford's JSLint](http://www.JSLint.com/lint.html).

For appending objects to other objects, you could do something like... (not tested)

```
for (var key in a_obj) {
    if (a_obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // avoid inherited properties
        data[key] = a_obj[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var a_key = 'element';

var a_val = 'value';

var a_obj = {a_key:a_val};

Comment: This does not do what you expect. You expect a_obj to be {"element":"value"} at the end of this, but it is actually {"a_key":"value"}.